# How to change line and hint colors of TextInputEditText programmatically?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android, textinputlayout

1) Getting color from the server

2) Than changing the line and hint of the TextInputEditText to that 
   color (for all states)

- I am using material:1.0.0 for androidx

Comment: Please add more context, such as sample code for what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

To set the color you can use:

```
// Sets the text color used by the hint in both the collapsed and expanded states
textInputLayout.setDefaultHintTextColor(...);

//Sets the collapsed hint text color
textInputLayout.setHintTextColor(....);
```

In a FilledBox layout to change the underline color you can use the method **`setBoxStrokeColor`**

```
setBoxStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color....));
```

You can use a single color or a selector like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks, and the line color?

Comment: Doesn't work
`
<TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">

        <TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />
    </TextInputLayout>
`
setBoxStrokeColor(Color.GREEN)

Comment: doesnt work for the line with `material:1.0.0`

and with `1.1.0-beta01` - it crashes

Comment: Use a resource R.color.xxxxx

Comment: Doesn't work or crashes? It is not the same. Post your crash.